# Massive-Distributed Parallel Execution of tasks

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

We are currently struggling with the following task. We need to run a windows application (single instance only working) 1000 times with different input parameters. One run of this application can take up to multiple hours. It feels like we have the same problem like any video rendering farm – each picture of a video should be calculated independently and parallel – but it is not rendering.

Currently we tried to execute it with Jenkins and Pipeline jobs. We used the parallel steps in pipeline and lets Jenkins queue and execute the application. We use the Jenkins Label Expression to lets Jenkins choose which job can be run on which node.

The limitation in Jenkins is currently with massive parallel jobs (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47724). When the queue contains multiple hundred jobs adding new jobs took much longer – will become even worse by increasing queue. And main problem: Jenkins will start the execution of parallel pipeline part-jobs only after finishing adding all to the queue.
We already investigated ideas how to solve this problem:

1. Python Distributed: https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

   a.    For single functions it looks great, but for the complete run like we have in Jenkins => Deploy and collect results looks complex

   b. Client->Server bidirectional communication needed – no chance to bring it online through a NAT (VM Server)
2. BOINC: https://boinc.berkeley.edu/

   a.    for our understanding we had to extend the backend in a massive way to bring our jobs working => to configure the jobs in BOINC we had to write a lot of new automating code

   b. currently we need a predeployed application which can differ between different inputs => no equivalent of Jenkins Label Expression

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks in advance